# Failed to create the agent 'processing/taskAgent'

Tags: processing

We have a CM - CD setup. On the CD server an error is getting logged:

```
Message: Failed to create the agent 'processing/taskAgent'
Source: Sitecore.Kernel
at Sitecore.Diagnostics.Assert.IsNotNull(Object value, String message)
at Sitecore.Diagnostics.Assert.IsNotNull(Object value, String format, Object[] args)
at Sitecore.Analytics.Core.BackgroundService.CreateAgent()
at Sitecore.Analytics.Core.BackgroundService.ExecuteAgent()
at Sitecore.Analytics.Core.BackgroundService.Run()
```

Could anyone let me know the root cause of the issue?

Answer (score 2):

Your error appear because you have processing/taskAgent inside the file **Sitecore.Analytics.Processing.Services.config**

```
<processing>
      <module type="Sitecore.Analytics.Processing.ProcessingModule" singleInstance="true">
        <BackgroundServices hint="list:Add">
          <taskagent type="Sitecore.Analytics.Core.BackgroundService">
            <param desc="agentName">processing/taskAgent</param>
            <Interval>0.00:00:15</Interval>
            <MaxThreads>1</MaxThreads>
          </taskagent>
        </BackgroundServices>
      </module>
    </processing>
```

According to "**How to configure Content Delivery server**" : https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up_and_maintaining/xdb/configuring_servers/configure_a_content_delivery_server this file should be disabled. Please have a look on  Config Enable Disable Excel spreadsheet for Sitecore X and enable/disable config file. Be careful you need to verify spreadsheet for your current solution I give you the link for version 8.2